# A Co-finite topology on $X$ is a discrete topology on $X$?(If $X$ is a finite set)

Tags: general-topology

So We need to show that our topology is power set of $X$. how can I proceed?

Comment: It's wrong in general. Otherwise there wouldn't be two distinct names for it. This question lacks context as such.

Comment: What is $X$? This is not true unless you have a specific $X$ in mind.

Comment: I don't know the exact details of the question, just remember my professor saying something like this. But i think the new edit gives sufficient information.

Comment: With the new edit, the result is now true, but it's also really elementary, and still lacks context. Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [cofinite topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness) on $X$ consists of the empty set and all cofinite sets, meaning all sets with finite complement. Since every subset of $X$ is finite, so is their complement. Therefore, the cofinite topology is equal to the power set.

Answer (score 0):

Given any set $X$, we can define a topology $\tau$ on it, called the *cofinite topology*, by declaring the empty set $\phi$ and all the cofinite (look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness) for the definition of cofinite subset) subsets of $X$ to be the open sets (why is this collection form a topology on $X$?).

Now if $X$ is finite then the complement of any subset of $X$ is open in $\tau$ (why?).